# What replaces egg in vegan sponge cakes?

Tags: vegan, sponge-cake

I already know there are a few vegan egg replacements, such as:

- Aquafaba
- Coconut milk
- One tablespoon of apple puree with 1 tablespoon of dense oil (coconut oil or corn oil I guess)
- Chickpea flour with some starches

I know that each one of these, as well as others I don't know → **aren't multipurpose** as eggs are and thus and should be used for different groups of recipes respectively.

What can replace eggs when making a vegan sponge cake?

Comment: I'm afraid you're not the first one to ask :)  When reading the duplicate target, do go into the linked questions on the right hand side, they also have some pertinent information in thsi case.

Comment: Hello; as my question is specifically about sponge cakes (and perhaps you know the define it way better than I do that this is a well based, well used term), I humbly doubt it is a duplicate... It is a unique representative of the site in search engines...

Comment: We are happy to reopen duplicate questions when they are different from the original. Currently, I have difficulty seeing where the difference is. Sponge cakes are cakes, and the answers on the other question cover sponge cakes - in fact, seeing that sponge cakes are one of the most common types of cake, I would say many answerers may have answered mostly with sponge cakes in mind. Maybe you can edit your question here so it is clear how it is different from the other one and why the answers from the other don't apply?

Comment: @rumtscho I could but per what you wrote I was thinking and kindly tell you it will be a waste of time.